# Kill running background jobs inside a shell script

Tags: shell

I have created a shell script that runs multiple processes in the background, and at the end listens for the user's keyboard, when enter is pressed, it kills the previously created processes.

Something like :

```
#!/bin/sh
process_1 &
process_2 &
process_3 &

read -p "PRESS [ENTER] TO TERMINATE PROCESSES." PRESSKEY

kill -2 `jobs -p`
```

Notice that I run the processes in the background (the later &), I thought that when I do something like :

```
kill -2 `jobs -p`
```

All the jobs running in the background would be killed, but it actually tells me that my command is invalid, so I assume that `jobs -p` doesn't return anything.

Any idea on how to kill process_1 process_2 and process_3 ?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the exact error? I can think of a number of reasons this might not be working. Two are that:

a) The jobs command is returning more than one process
b) The jobs command is not returning any output

Comment: The error is :""" kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus] """

Comment: Try adding this line before the kill command: `echo "$(jobs -p)"`

Comment: Added it, same output kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]

Comment: If it is not printing anything for `jobs -p` that means that it is not returning any output.

Comment: Try using `killall process_1 && killall process_2 && killall process_3`

Comment: process_1 is actually `java -jar myfile.jar`, I doubt that killall java is the way to go :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44531/discussion-between-735tesla-and-user2848844)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the PIDs in a space separated list and kill that:

```
process_1 & pids="${pids-} $!"
process_2 & pids="${pids-} $!"
process_3 & pids="${pids-} $!"

read -p "PRESS [ENTER] TO TERMINATE PROCESSES." PRESSKEY

kill -2 $pids # Without quotes to make the PIDs separate arguments
```

(The `${pids-}` syntax is to avoid errors when using `set -o nounset`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
kill $(ps|grep 'process_1'|awk '{print $1}')
```

Explanation:
`ps` returns a list of running process. We `grep` for only the one we want to kill and the use `awk` to get only the PID of the process.

Comment: -1 You can use `pgrep` instead of `ps | grep`, and [this is dangerous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_do_I_kill_a_process_by_name.3F__I_need_to_get_the_PID_out_of_ps_aux_.7C_grep_....).